# opengl viewModelMatrix from opencv pose matrix

Tags: java, android, opencv, opengl-es, homography

I have calculated the pose matrix using the cameraPoseFromHomography() function, please how to build the opengl viewModelMatrix from the pose matrix (3*4) obtained by opencv.I am working on an android aplication in java.

```
 Mat homography = Calib3d.findHomography(ReferencePoints2, ReferencePoints1,0,Calib3d.RANSAC);
 Mat pose = cameraPoseFromHomography(homography);

 private static Mat cameraPoseFromHomography(Mat h) {
    //Log.d("DEBUG", "cameraPoseFromHomography: homography " + matToString(h));

    Mat pose = Mat.eye(3, 4, CvType.CV_32FC1);  // 3x4 matrix, the camera pose
    float norm1 = (float) Core.norm(h.col(0));
    float norm2 = (float) Core.norm(h.col(1));
    float tnorm = (norm1 + norm2) / 2.0f;       // Normalization value

    Mat normalizedTemp = new Mat();
    Core.normalize(h.col(0), normalizedTemp);
    normalizedTemp.convertTo(normalizedTemp, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    normalizedTemp.copyTo(pose.col(0)); // Normalize the rotation, and copies the column to pose

    Core.normalize(h.col(1), normalizedTemp);
    normalizedTemp.convertTo(normalizedTemp, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    normalizedTemp.copyTo(pose.col(1));// Normalize the rotation and copies the column to pose

    Mat p3 = pose.col(0).cross(pose.col(1)); // Computes the cross-product of p1 and p2
    p3.copyTo(pose.col(2));// Third column is the crossproduct of columns one and two

    Mat temp = h.col(2);
    double[] buffer = new double[3];
    h.col(2).get(0, 0, buffer);
    pose.put(0, 3, buffer[0] / tnorm);  //vector t [R|t] is the last column of pose
    pose.put(1, 3, buffer[1] / tnorm);
    pose.put(2, 3, buffer[2] / tnorm);



    return pose;
}
```